# Magento 2 : fetch checkout session on new route page after place order

Tags: magento2

How can I fetch checkout session on new route controller (redirecting to new page after place order) after order is placed. Adding checkout session to constructor and fetching getlastorderid using it is not working.

Block :

```
protected $_coreRegistryl;
protected $_checkoutSession;
protected $_remote;
protected $orderFactory;
protected $_objectManager;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order,
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $om,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\RemoteAddress $remote
        ) {
    $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
    $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    $this->_order = $order;
    $this->_objectManager = $om;
    $this->_remote = $remote;
    $this->orderFactory = $orderFactory;
    parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory);
}

public function getOrder()
{
    $orderId = $this->_checkoutSession->getLastOrderId();
    return $this->orderFactory->create()->load($orderId);
}

protected function _prepareForm()
{
    $model = $this->getModel();
    $order = $this->getOrder();
    if($order->getId() && $this->_checkoutSession->getData('session_check') == '1') {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
        $form = $this->_formFactory->create( .....
```

Answer (score 2):

`getlastorderid` should NOT exist anymore after redirecting from the order success page.

Two possible solutions would be:

1. to add the order_id as a url perimeter to your redirect page (assuming no sensitive information will be disclose on this page)
2. Set a new session before redirection which would be a more secure way(please remember to unset it)

Take a look at /app/code/Magento/Checkout/Controller/Onepage/Success.php

```
class Success extends \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage
{
    /**
     * Order success action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $session = $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout();
        if (!$this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Checkout\Model\Session\SuccessValidator')->isValid()) {
            return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('checkout/cart');
        }
        $session->clearQuote();
```

Comment: But I want getlastorderid before checkout success page and after place order on my new page. Issue i am facing is if i disable page cache in cache management then i am able to get order or checkoutSession, but not otherwise. Does it make any sense? Not able to find the solution.

Comment: If your debugging is correct ... then it seem to be a block cacheing issue

Comment: How should we resolve this?

Comment: Can you add some code... controller and block if any?

Comment: Thanks, its working after making cacheable to false in layout xml file.

Comment: still there is problem. my method renderer file code: 
            
            afterPlaceOrder: function () {
                window.location.replace(url.build('mycustom/testmodule/payment/'));
            },

Comment: see updated question with code.

Comment: `afterPlaceOrder` is not in the code above

Answer (score 1):

Its working with after making cacheable to false in layout xml file. 
Its not the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

I am not getting order data or custom data from checkout session. This is creating an issue in CCAvenue redirection as I'm not getting last order id from the session. This does not happen always but randomly. Please suggest what can be done.